# Как лучше запросить разрешения в рантайме?

Tags: android

Принялся адаптировать приложение под Android 6 и выше. Очень много разрешений. Как лучше всего из запрашивать? Будет ли хорошо при первом запуске их по очереди запрашивать? Для каждого разрешения есть объяснение, зачем оно нужно.

Comment: Уверен, пользователю будет спокойнее и понятнее, если разрешение будет запрашиваться именно в тот момент, когда понадобилось. Тем более, что у него есть признаки паранойи, если он не одобрил все запрошенные разрешения при установке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучшими вариантами считаю 2 из тех, что встречал:

1. При первом запуске во время показа приветствия кратенько описывается какой-либо функционал, указывается что для этого необходимо такое-то разрешение и затем оно запрашивается.
2. Непосредственно перед использованием того что требует разрешения с объяснением зачем оно нужно и что не будет работать, если это разрешение не дать.

Ну и в любом случае повторный запрос разрешений, если пользователь запретил, но снова пытается использовать то что требует разрешения.

Comment: За повторный (пятый, сотый) запрос пользователь удалит приложение ко всем чертям. Лучше пункт в настройках "повторно запросить разрешения" подобный вашему первому пункту.